# Return an empty field name from validation form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

http://jsfiddle.net/3vHxF/ Here is what I tried

And my html code is :

```
 <form id="commentForm" style="width:200px;" name="MYFORM" action="#">
                  <label>
                     <strong>Enquiry Form </strong>
                  </label>
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input id="name" type="text" size="30" name="name">
                  <label>Phone No</label>
                  <input id="phone" type="text" size="30" name="phone">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input id="email" type="text"size="30" name="email">
                  <label>Message</label><br>
                  <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                  <input id="Send" type="submit" value="Send" onclick="send()">
                  </form>

Javascript is :

var name=getElementById('name');
var phone=getElementById('phone');
var email=getElementById('email');
var mess=getElementById('message');

function send(){

if(name==null&&phone==null&&email==null&&mess==null)
    alert('field is empty');
}
```

I want to alert the field which is empty, and at the same time I want to write it simply. Please don't suggest any plug-ins.

Comment: For that you have to check each input field.

Comment: @RajInevitable this is not what i want.. i don't know how?? so only i posted here brother

Comment: Change getElementById to document.getElementById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following jQuery:

```
$(":text,textarea").each(function() {
    $(this).css("outline", $(this).val() ? "1px solid red" : "none");
});
```

---

Sorry, I thought "no plugins" meant "no jQuery plugins." (You would call jQuery a library or dependency, not a "plugin")

This is a mostly untested non-jQuery version:

```
function highlightMissingInputs() {
    for (var formIndex = 0; formIndex < document.forms.length; formIndex++) {
        var form = document.forms[formIndex];
        for (var inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < form.length; inputIndex++) {
            var input = form[inputIndex];
            switch (input.tagName) {
                case "INPUT":
                    var typeAttribute = input.attributes.type;
                    if (typeAttribute) {
                        var type = (typeAttribute.value || "").toLowerCase();
                        switch (type) {
                            case undefined:
                            case "":
                            case "text":
                            case "email":
                            case "tel":
                            case "email":
                            case "search":
                                break;
                            default:
                                continue;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "TEXTAREA":
                    break;
                default:
                    continue;
            }

            input.style.outline = input.value ? "none" : "1px solid red";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to do in javascript only.. @Joseph Lennox

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript, it's just been written by someone else. (There are plenty of reasons for wanting to avoid it, but don't deny that it is JS).

Answer (score 2):

Your problems:

- You are testing HTMLInputElement objects and not the values they hold (so get the value)
- You are comparing strings to `null` (compare to an empty string)
- Your failure condition is based on *all* of them failing instead of *any* of them failing (use *or* not *and*)

Such:

```
if(name.value === "" || phone.value === "" || email.value === "" || mess.value === "")
    alert('field is empty');
}
```

To determine *which* one is empty, you need to test them one at a time instead of in a single `if` statement with `||`s.

Comment: Very well put, however this doesn't solve his actual question "I want to alert the field which is empty." Your solution only alerts "field is empty" no matter which is empty.

Comment: It's probably just a scope error on jsfiddle's side... Try it on your own script (and update getElementById to document.getElementById)

Comment: @saikiran — I missed that you were calling `getElementById` as a global instead of as a member of the `document` object. You had also configured JS Fiddle to make `send` a local function and it was out of scope of the onclick attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/3vHxF/9/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the click handler from the button and put a submit handler on the form:

```
<form id="commentForm" onsubmit="return validat(this);" ... >
```

Now you can do a simple validation:

```
function validate(form) {
  var control;
  var isValid = true;

  for (var i=0, iLen=form.elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = form.elements[i];

    if (control.value == '') {
      alert('Field ' + control.name + ' is empty'); 
      isValid = false;
    }
  }
  return isValid; // false cancels submit
}
```

That is a very minimal validation script, but it's a start.

Incidentally, since your form controls have names (which are required to be successful), they don't need ids.

Answer (score 1):

Not a clean approach. But try developing the below code.

```
var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;
var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
var mess=document.getElementById('message').value;

function send(){

if(isEmpty(name, 'name') || isEmpty(phone, 'phone') || isEmpty(email, 'email') || isEmpty(mess, 'message')) {
  return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function isEmpty(val, fld) {
    if(val && val != null) {
        return true;
    }
    alert(fld +" is Empty");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
var name=getElementById('name');
var phone=getElementById('phone');
var email=getElementById('email');
var mess=getElementById('message');
```

to

```
  var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;
var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
var mess=document.getElementById('message').value;
```

and then use

```
if(name.value === "" || phone.value === "" || email.value === "" || mess.value === "")
    alert('field is empty');
}
```

Comment: @saikiran  you need to use var name=document.getElementById('name').value;

Comment: sorry i forgot it while pasting

Comment: @saikiran which one you are saying